# Scripting code for class imbalance in Biolabs Orange

Tags: python, orange, class-imbalance, smote, anaconda

I'm trying to manipulate some data in Biolabs Orange, using the built in Python Script widget and information at [Biolabs Orange tutorial on scripting](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/tutorial/data.html).

However, I'm struggling with taking the results of SMOTE and putting them into a format for Orange:

This is the code I'm using in the Python Script widget:

```
# Get libraries
import Orange
import numpy as np
from Orange.data import Domain, Table
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

#in_data = Orange.data.Table('WORKING_temp.csv')

df = in_data.copy()

# set variables for SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

# get table of data (X) and class variables (y)
X, y = df.X, df.Y

# resample data and classes
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_sample(X, y)


df.X = X_res
df.Y = y_res

temp = Orange.data.Table(df.X, df.Y)
temp.domain = df.domain

out_data = Orange.data.Table(temp)
```

The result is a ValueError, which I think is related to changing the length of the class variables and data table, while leaving the original index length?

```
"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3724,10) into shape (3724)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the Orange team, I was able to solve the problem!
[Link to thread on github](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/2995)

The following code can be pasted into a Python Script widget, and will balance your classes before training a classifier in Orange:

```
# Get libraries
import Orange
import numpy as np
from Orange.data import Domain, Table
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

# How Orange passes data to widget
df = in_data.copy()

# set variables for SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

# get table of data (X) and class variables (y)
X, y = df.X, df.Y

# resample data and classes
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_sample(X, y)

# Get the target and feature variables
d = Domain(df.domain.attributes, df.domain.class_vars)

# Create a new Orange Table object with the appropriate headers
# This is how Orange passes the data on to the next widget
out_data = Orange.data.Table(d, X_res, y_res)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me too, appreciate your looping back from the Orange team's help and posting it back here! (Interestingly, the scikit-learn being used by my update Orange installation 13.3 - was an outdated rev 0.18 of scikit-learn - so I had to upgrade to sklearn 0.19.1 within the Orange installation first, before installing the latest imblearn package - before getting SMOTE as used in the script to work)

Comment: This answer no longer works with the current version of imblearn

Answer (score 0):

This works with the latest version of imblearn. You have to import imblearn from Orange's add-ons, add-more menu though.

```
# Get libraries
import Orange
import numpy as np
from Orange.data import Domain, Table
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

# How Orange passes data to widget
df = in_data.copy()

# set variables for SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

# get table of data (X) and class variables (y)
X, y = df.X, df.Y

# resample data and classes
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)

# Get the target and feature variables
d = Domain(df.domain.attributes, df.domain.class_vars)

# Create a new Orange Table object with the appropriate headers
# This is how Orange passes the data on to the next widget
out_data = Orange.data.Table(d, X_res, y_res)
```