# Orange data mining: Balancing data set using imblearn code

Tags: python, orange, imbalanced-learn

I am using an unbalanced dataset. I wanted to oversample my dataset using a Python script ([Scripting code for class imbalance in Biolabs Orange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30206/scripting-code-for-class-imbalance-in-biolabs-orange)). However, it still gives me an error

```
"No module named imblearn".
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Class imbalance almost certainly is not a problem, and there is no need to use oversampling to solve a non-problem. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

To install a Python package select:

```
options > add-ons > add more > insert package name
```

So to install the  imblearn package :

```
options > add-ons > add more > imblearn
```